# image grow effect with keyboard event

Tags: jquery, html

i have an application that grows image gradually when mouse is placed on that i want similar kind of image grow effect with keyboard event i.e, focus/blur instead of mouseover/mouseout.

here is my code of image grow with mouseover/mouseout:
[demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/jAxg9/29/)

i want same to be done with keyboard events so i placed image inside button and replaced mouseover/mouseout with focus/blur it does work,but image inside button with mouseover/mouseout works.i am confused please help. [demo1](http://www.jsfiddle.net/jAxg9/30/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a workaround approach (since you can't directly `focus` an image element):

```
<a href="#" class="foci"><img src="something.png" /></a>
```

With the following CSS:

```
a.foci {
    cursor: default;
}
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #ffa;
}
a:focus img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4zAbN/).

---

**Edited** to provide jQuery animation effect:

```
$('a:has(img)').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).find('img').animate(
            {
                'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px'
            }, 1500);
    });
$('a:has(img)').blur(
    function(){
        $(this).find('img').animate(
            {
                'width': '100px',
                'height': '100px'
            }, 1500);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4zAbN/1/).

Comment: @rashmi, no problem at all; see the edit for the jQuery-specific animation effect =)

Comment: yes thanks for your help. David if you dont mind can you paste complete code in html section of jsfiddle itself. sorry to trouble you.

Comment: please do update complete code in html section of jsfiddle David. :(

Comment: im sorry david. no need to post code. i got output. i actually wanted if you have made use of any jquery library. thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have "focus" on an image. Only form elements which have input can have be the focus of the keyboard, thus an image cannot be the cause of a focus or blur event.

Comment: i agree with your answer so only i placed image inside button. now button does get focus right. even button wont grow in size using focus/blur property but where as button grows in size using mouseover/mouseout. i hope you got my point now

Comment: You know that I don't have your hard drive mounted on my computer, so `F:\rashmi\icons_tv\Help_Normal.png` isn't an image that I can see in your demo. Aside from that, people don't expect to be able to have focus on an image, so why do you require this?

Comment: i want to build application with only keyboard events. as part of my application i want grow image gradually till specified size.

Comment: In what way would you like the keyboard to control the zooming of your image, because it doesn't sound as though being able to blur and focus will be helpful.

Comment: say for example if i select particular button with tab key that button should zoomin.

Comment: Yes but why, what benefit does it give your users. Because they will surely not be expecting such functionality and in such a way. Just trying to understand the reason behind your request.

Comment: its because i finally have to port it on the device which does not support mouse.

Comment: OK, then there are other far better standard ways you could about this. What you have proposed it a hack, since it is using an in place mechanism for a purpose other than the intended one. On such devices other JavaScript events are available, such as `touchstart`, `touchend` etc. which I would use to achieve the same effect.